# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool' Xamarin alert

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, async-await

So, I've been trying to use an alert with a callback. I want the user to go back to the main page when they click the "ok" button.

According to 
Xamarin's documentation from stackoverflow: /documentation/xamarin.forms/4883/display-alert#t=20171005164124370635
I'm doing it properly, but I cannot get it to work. Already tried differente declaration methods but nothing seems to work.

```
    async void ConfirmationAlert(String resp){
        if (await DisplayAlert(resp, "", "OK"))
        {
            MasterLogin.Perfil mPerfil = new MasterLogin.Perfil();
            mPerfil.mainPage = mainPage;
            mainPage.Master = mPerfil;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code that gives you the error. What makes you think we can guess the domain for that partial URL you pasted in? What does DisplayAlert() return, just plain Task?

Comment: I'm sorry, stackoverflow didn't allow me to post the full link, that's why I mentioned it was stackoverflow's documentation, it's stackoverflow.com/doc...

Comment: It doesn't even compile right now, because of the error mentioned on the title @ line 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calling the overload that returns void, see [Display Alert Void](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayAlert/p/System.String/System.String/System.String/) and [Display Alert Bool](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayAlert/p/System.String/System.String/System.String/System.String/) You'll need to supply the parameter `string accept` to get the proper overload.

Comment: The string parameter is there, the only one not included is the cancel parameter. Do I need to include that one too for it to work?

Comment: just get rid of the IF statement.  If they can only choose OK, there is no point in testing the response.

Comment: Yes the method that returns `Task<bool>` requires all four parameters to give the user a choice and the `bool` represents that choice. Supplying only three parameters doesn't give the user a choice and consequently doesn't return a value.

Comment: Looks like it was indeed the 4th parameter that had to be included for it to work. Now it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayAlert` with three params does not return a `bool`, so you cannot use it within an `if` statement.